# Open skype URI from win 7 desktop app

Tags: wpf, windows, uri, skype

[Here](http://blogs.skype.com/2012/09/26/use-skype-uris-to-start-skype/) the closest I can find is how to open skype links from Win8 JS apps.

So my closest to the solution in a Win7 desktop (WPF) app is:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("skype:[SkypeID]");
```

But this is not what I wanted, this really starts a new Skype process; it won't open the skype url with a running skype instance.
I can do that from any browser with hyperlinks.
I can do that on OS X with this code:

```
AppKit.NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("skype:[SkypeID]"));
```

So how do I open skype links from Win 7 apps with a running skype instance?